# Intermittent problem with update query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I have an UPDATE query that is intermittently behaving in an unexpected way. The context is that I have a table for storing phone numbers alongside a user_id (user_id is foreign key from main Users table). The phone column is of type Number. I am updating the phone number through a button on the main form, and the event handler is pasted below.

```
Private Sub button_add_phone_Click()

Dim phone_query As String
Dim phone_number As String
Dim user_query As String
Dim user_id As Integer
Dim user_rs As DAO.recordset
Dim curr_db As DAO.Database

Set curr_db = CurrentDb()

If Not IsNull(Form!hidden_user_id) Then
    user_id = Form!hidden_user_id
Else
    MsgBox "Select a user to proceed."
    Exit Sub
End If

phone_number = Form!Phone

user_query = "select * from AVIT_Phone where user_id = " & user_id
Set user_rs = curr_db.OpenRecordset(user_query, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

If user_rs.EOF Then
    phone_query = "insert into AVIT_Phone (user_id, phone) values (" & user_id & ", '" & phone_number & "')"
Else
    phone_query = "update AVIT_Phone set phone = " & phone_number & " where user_id = " & user_id
End If

curr_db.execute phone_query, dbSQLPassThrough

MsgBox "Phone number updated for user " & Form!text_name

curr_db.Close

Set user_rs = Nothing
Set curr_db = Nothing

End Sub
```

The intermittent problem that I am encountering is that occasionally, the update query is setting the phone to NULL rather than the value from the textbox (Form!phone).

I thought initially that there is some formatting error or type conversion error, but the intermittency of it suggests that there is something else happening.

Please let me know if you see anything in the code which would cause this behavior.

Comment: Update: I am finding that when entering a phone number that starts with "1" the update works as expected. 

I stepped through with the debugger but not seeing why the update query is failing when it does not start with 1.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in your form module's Declarations section?  If not, add it and then run Debug->compile from the VB Editor's main menu.

Comment: Hi HansUp, I do not see a problem with assignment of phone_number variable. Debug.Print shows phone_number picking up the correct value. 

I do not have Option Explicit in this module, because I inherited this project and none of the other modules (there are many) have the Explicit option. I am not sure if I should add it to this file specifically.

Comment: The INSERT should fail because of apostrophe delimiters. Do not use apostrophe delimiters with number type fields. A phone number is not a number, it is an identifier - make it a text field. Why is phone number not in main users table - why a separate table?  Give controls name different from phone, like tbxPhone then reference control name like: `Me.tbxPhone`.

Comment: Not necessary to open a recordset just to check if a value exists in table - can use DLookup(). `If IsNull(DLookup("phone", "AVIT_Phone", "User_ID=" & Me.tbxUser)) Then`.

Comment: HansUp, I have noticed the pattern you mention (Forms!FormName!TextboxName) in other code examples including in my project, where there is a collection of objects called Forms. I always assumed that "Form" just referenced the current form that is associated with the code file. 

Any thoughts related to my first comment? The update works when the first digit of entered phone number is "1". Fails otherwise.

Comment: June7, thanks for the suggestion about DLookUp.

Comment: Sorry, that caught me by surprise.  It seems that within a form's code module, `Form` is a valid synonym for `Me`.  I been doing this for 20 yrs., but never saw that!

Comment: Why is first digit "1"? Is this country code? Put country code in a separate field. If field is number type, what field size? Did you see questions in my other comment?

Comment: June7, I am looking into the apostrophe delimiter (in particular the way I have used it in my update query). Still relatively new to VBA, so not used to the type conversions and other language features. 

Phone number is in a separate table because we are expecting only a small subset of users to have phone number recorded, so wanted to avoid having a column in main Users table with mostly NULL values. 

Have changed control from Form!Phone to Form!text_phone as you suggested. It did not fix the problem though :).

Comment: There is no reason for the first digit being "1" - it is not the country code. I am just entering 10 digits into the textbox and trying to save, and seeing the update only works as expected when first digit is "1". 

Column in table is of data type "Number". I wonder if there is an overflow situation happening when converting to number here.

Comment: Pretty sure there is an overflow problem. It also works if the first digit is "0". 

Thanks for advice on looking into field size of number type, looks like running into maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (field size of Number data type is Long Integer)

What is the best approach from here? Change it to Double?

Comment: I already suggested making it a text field. That's what I do with phone numbers and SSN.

Comment: June7, thanks for advice. You are correct, phone number should be a text field.

Comment: I would include field in main table and tolerate empty fields. A number field would drop leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, phone numbers were entered as 10-digit values which were causing an over-flow in the phone number column which was of data type Number. Field Size of the column was Long Integer, which has range of values -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647.

Solution is to store phone number as a text field rather than numeric field, as suggested by June7.